# iOS: Selecting through UITextView on custom UITableViewCell

Tags: uitableview, ios

I have a custom UITableViewCell with an image and UITextView property. The textview spans to the edge of the cell. My problem is tapping the textview does not register in didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

How can I make it so that I can "click through" my textview?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't need it to be editable, just set your text view's `enabled` property to NO.

Comment: A textView doesn't have an enabled property.

Answer (score 7):

For `UITextView` set `textView.userInteractionEnabled = false` and if you have `UITextField`, set `textField.userInteractionEnabled = false`.

If you want the textView or textField to be editable after the cell with it is tapped, do something like this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
  tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

  let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)! as UITableViewCell

  // find first textField inside this cell and select it
  for case let textField as UITextField in cell.subviews {
    textField.userInteractionEnabled = true
    textField.becomeFirstResponder()
    return
  }

  // find first textView inside this cell and select it
  for case let textView as UITextView in cell.subviews {
    textView.userInteractionEnabled = true
    textView.becomeFirstResponder()
    return
  }
}
```

Then make sure to disable user interaction after you finish editing:

```
  func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    textField.userInteractionEnabled = false
    // rest of the function
  }

  func textViewDidEndEditing(textView: UITextView) {
    textView.userInteractionEnabled = false
    // rest of the function
  }
```

Don't forget to set the `UITextFieldDelegate` and/or `UITextViewDelegate`

I hope this helped someone :)

Comment: I had been setting my `UITextView`'s `editable` property to `NO`, which didn't work. Setting `userInteractionEnabled` to `NO` worked.

Answer (score 3):

You can assign a delegate to your UITextView, and in its textViewShouldBeginEditing: method, you can manually call the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method. If you can't easily get the indexPath of the row to select, you can use a subclass of UITextView that has an indexPath property, and in cellForRowAtIndexPath: method, when you create your UITextView, set the indexPath property.

Comment: You can also call selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition here to get the highlight animation on the table cell if you desire that behavior.