# iPhone - Custom UITableViewCell with clickable UITextView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I created a custom `UITableViewCell` and placed a `UITextView` element on it. Now when I click on the `UITextView` inside the cell `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` is not called (in the superview which is a `UITableViewController`).

Should I make the `UITextView` "transparent" or something? How can I do that? I get the same effect when adding a button.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Adjust the `userInteractionEnabled` property to `NO`

```
someTextView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

Documentation here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/userInteractionEnabled

Similar question here: [iOS: Selecting through UITextView on custom UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4045736/ios-selecting-through-uitextview-on-custom-uitableviewcell)